# Showing multiple shared calendars from Exchange (O365) in SharePoint (O365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar, exchange-online

I have the need for presenting multiple shared calendars for a group of people from Exchange (O365) on a page in SharePoint (O365). My research shows that this is not supported out of the box, so I will either have to purchase or develop my own web part to do this.

Is it in any way possible to develop a web part in SharePoint for Office365 which can communicate with EWS for Exchange for Office365, and present this data? I've found indicators in various articles online suggesting that this may not be possible.

How would you normally go about solving something like these? I imagine that having a calendar view for a group of consultants based on their Exchange calendars from Office365 is a very normal need in most IT companies, so I'm a bit puzzled that this is not supported out of the box.

Would you develop or would you purchase? If you would purchase, what would you purchase?

Comment: @wjervis Ah, I read something about being able to show REST data in SharePoint Online! Are you saying that there is a way to parse and present this in SP Online?

Comment: I can't figure out how to auth with the service using username and password..

Comment: It can't detected the credentials for Exchange Online from a SharePoint Online workflow apparently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18865/discussion-between-wjervis-and-maritim).