# Can I display Exchange Online Calendar in SharePoint Online at present?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, overlay, exchange-online

I am already aware that this question is already asked multiple times on this site but almost all are for SharePoint Server. And I found [one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121974/showing-multiple-shared-calendars-from-exchange-o365-in-sharepoint-o365) for SharePoint Online but this talks about custom development.

I have gone through the following posts,

["The HTTP request is unauthorized" error in a SharePoint Online calendar after you configure a calendar overlay to Exchange Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2997170/-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-error-in-a-sharepoint-online-calenda)

[Overlay Exchange Calendar in SharePoint](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/overlay-exchange-calendar-in-sharepoint/04ed751f-6b97-4840-b4fb-2346c4feeed3)

Here it is clearly mentioned that Overlaying Exchange Online Calendar in SharePoint Online is not possible. But this post is last updated on

> **Article ID: 2997170 - Last Review: Dec 20, 2016 - Revision: 1**
>
> **Applies to  Microsoft SharePoint Online, Microsoft Exchange Online**

They also have given link to [uservoice](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273492-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/8487706-fix-the-ablility-to-overlay-an-exchange-calendar-o), but I am not able log-in.

So, I want to know the status of this at present.

Is it possible to integrate Exchange Online Calendar in SharePoint Online at present?

**Edit:**

I have resource mailbox configured. I want to display the events added for this mailbox should be displayed in SharePoint Online. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where Microsoft aren't completely useless was listening to gripes concerning the SharePoint Forms/Flow, as they did actually fix a few concerns I had. Perhaps they were really simple requests... Although, I suppose the request from the hundreds of people trying to simply get 2 online products talking to each other (Exchange Online & SharePoint Online) must too complicated for them to handle so they have probably ditched it permanently. This is a deep Shame, as it seems like using Microsoft products are complicated enough without the added frustration of having two platforms that are both appar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this could be something Microsoft has in the roadmap of SharePoint Online. There is an option of using Exchange calendars on Office 365 Groups because it is integrated in fact. Office 365 Groups are much more than a simple SharePoint site and have features from Exchange.

Take a look at the following links:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2,
- https://sharepointmaven.com/top-5-features-office-365-groups/

Answer (score 0):

To overlay an Exchange calendar, follow these steps:

- In a SharePoint calendar, in the ribbon, on the Calendar tab, click Calendar Overlays.
- In the Calendar Overlay Settings page, click New Calendar.
- In the Name and Type section, type the Calendar Name and select Exchange.